# Why does the last call execute 3 times?

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, observable

I have this piece of code that is called from a component:

```
choose(n?: number): Observable<PickQuality[]> {
    var chosenObserver: Observer<PickQuality[]>;
    alert(n); // <-- Notice this line

    this.getOptions().subscribe(options => {
            alert(n); // <-- And this one
            this.reevaluate();

            var sorted = options.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
            var chosen: PickQuality[];

            if(n) chosen = sorted.slice(0, n);
            else chosen = sorted.slice(0, 1);

            chosenObserver.next(chosen);
    });

    let obs = new Observable<PickQuality[]>(observer => chosenObserver = observer);
    return obs;
}
```

The call is the following:

```
    test.choose().subscribe(a => console.log(a));
    test.choose(5).subscribe(b => console.log(b));
    test.choose(15).subscribe(c => console.log(c));
```

The 1st call to alert prints properly ("undefined", "5", "15") but the 2nd prints "15" 3 times. Why odes this happen? It was working properly but some change I made (and couldn't track) changed this and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Hi Luis. Your code looks convoluted. You have a function creating obsA, then subscribing to obsB to emit values on obsA, then finally returning obsC that wraps obsA.... Surely this can be simplified. Can you describe **conceptually** what your `choose()` function is supposed to achieve?

Comment: PickQuality has an object (fetched via HTTP GET request) associated to a score. My getOption() fetches an array of those and choose(n?) is supposed to return a n-sized subarray sorted by these scores.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but I think you want to share subscriptions via share().

When the number of observers subscribed to the published observable goes from 0 to 1, we connect to the underlying observable sequence.

When the second subscriber is added, no additional subscriptions are added to the
underlying observable sequence. As a result the operations that result in side
effects are not repeated per subscriber.

```
constructor() {
   this.observable = ....share()
}

getOptions() {
   return this.observable;
}
```

Comment: But I only have one observer, which is the service that contains my choose() code. Isn't the obersable supposed to be created and returned in order for my component to call .subscribe()?

Comment: Yes there will be one observable, but multiple subscriptions will be added. If you want to share the subscription (so its not repeated per subscriber), then use the `share` operator.

Comment: I tried using an Observable field on my class and doing `if(!this.obs) return new Observable<PickQuality[]>(observer => chosenObserver = observer);`
`else return this.obs.share();` but it doesn't seem to work either